# Java SSL connection fails after disabling TLS1

Tags: java, ssl, java.security

I have a Java client that connects to an HTTPS server. That server can use any of TLS1_1 TLS1_2 TLS1_3.

With default java.security settings:

```
jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
```

My client fails miserably with:

```
 javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites
 are inappropriate)
```

Which I understand as *"I don't have implementation for anything that is allowed"*.

When I comment out jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms:

```
#jdk.tls.disabledAlgorithms=SSLv3, TLSv1, RC4, DES, MD5withRSA, \
    DH keySize < 1024, EC keySize < 224, 3DES_EDE_CBC, anon, NULL
```

My client fails less miserably, but fails anyway due to the server not willing to talk over TLS1:

```
Produced ClientHello handshake message (
"ClientHello": {
  "client version"      : "TLSv1",

...

Received alert message (
"Alert": {
  "level"      : "fatal",
  "description": "protocol_version"
}

..

Fatal (PROTOCOL_VERSION): Received
fatal alert: protocol_version (
"throwable" : {
  javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: protocol_version
```

I am using OpenJDK 17 on Red Hat Enterprise Server 8.7. My Java client uses Jersey REST client.

Why does my Java client not want to start handshake with higher TLS versions?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Which Jersey version are you using?